# Why doesn't my de-multiplexer with the selected signal assignment work?

Tags: vhdl, vivado, test-bench

It might be a stupid question...
I want to make a de-multiplexer  with one input: a , a byte and two outputs, x and y(also bytes).
there is also a signal input : s
The de-multiplexer should work with the selected signal assignment.
Whenever s is 1, x should be the value of a. When s is 0, the value of y should be the value of a.

```
       with s select x <= a when '1';
   with s select y <= a when '0';
```

when i put it in a process like this:

```
p1 : process (s,a)

   with s select x <= a when '1';
   with s select y <= a when '0';
```

end process;

I made a testbench and used it to test my dmux, when i trie to run it, it says that  i didn't use al possibilities, but I did? Right?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a  a problem statement. Provide a [mcve] including a description of the problem and the means to replicate it.

Comment: I edited my question with some extra info

Comment: ok, i fixed it, I forgot the others statement...

Comment: A selected signal assignment has an equivalent case statement, where all the choices must be covered. The base type of s isn't provided. If it's declared as type std_logic the base type is std_ulogic, a character enumeration type with possible values 'U', X', '0'. '1', 'Z', 'W', 'L', 'H', and '-'. What is the type of s? Are all the choices covered?

Comment: entity dmux is
 Port (
 a : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
 s : in std_logic;
 x : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
 y : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
  );
end dmux;

Comment: as a test i tried this:

Comment: with s select x <= a when '1', a when others;     
       with s select y <= a when '0', a when others;

Comment: but that made my x and y always the same as a, which is logical, the program runs now, but doesn't doe what i want

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (["why isn't this code working?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question** itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i edited my question again ;p

Comment: shouldn't i just replace the a that stands before when others, with 0000000, because that is what a normal de-multiplexer gives as output?

Comment: **in the question itself**, comments aren't searched, leaving future readers seeing no value in your question as a resource. Your last comment isn't clear without seeing the complete statement, any declarations for objects in your code.  "doesn't doe what i want" doesn't provide the desired behavior, nor did your question edit. Your selected signal assignments do what your edit describes. It's not reproducible. Are you describing simulation behavior or synthesized logic behavior? There's a distinction in how you'd use the others choice, the former would propagate 'X's and require a '0' choice.

Comment: It was a stupid question afterall, I doubt ic or its answer could be seen as resource...

Comment: The question could be transformed into something useful, particularly when also answered see [Why does my selected signal assignment not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415482/why-does-my-selected-signal-assignment-not-work) All the question and answering guidelines are intended to produce a useful search resource. It starts with a question with a clear problem statement and the ability to test the problem and solution against that encountered by future readers with similar  or identical problems.