# Why does my selected signal assignment not work?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

What did I do wrong with the selected signal assignment in my `VHDL` code?

```
with s select x <= a when (s = '1')
         else y <= a when (s = '0');
```

I also tried this:

```
with s select x <= a when '1';
with s select y <= a when '0';
```

Comment: "not work" is a bit vague. Provide a [mcve] including a description of the problem and the means to replicate it.

Comment: Questions and answers are meant to be a search resource for future readers with questions. Without a clear problem statement (what indication do you get your signal assignment statement isn't working?)  Your question isn't clear. Answering the question also likely depends on the declaration of `s` which isn't provided. A selected signal assignment has a case statement (in a process statement) equivalent. A case statement requires every choice of the value of s be covered. For type bit they are, for std_logic (std_ulogic) not. As is your question isn't answerable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completly clear what you want to do. From what you showed us, it seems to me that you want to create a demux controlled by signal s (1 input, 2 outputs), where x <= a when s='1' and y <= a when s='0'

The use of select should be done in cases when you want to create a mux (n inputs, 1 output). That is, the opposite of a demux!

I would recommend you to use a simple if statement to create a demux.

Example:

`if s='1' then x <= a; else y <= a; end if;`